# RxJs mergeScan operators can not accumulate by stream flatMap from a Promise?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I want to accumulate stream from flatMap promise, I find a opreator names "mergeScan" can flat stream and accumlate them。
But when I tried it ,I found it doesn't work when promise in the stream, but it works correctly without promise.

```
    const Rx = require('rxjs/Rx');
    const {
      of ,
    } = require('rxjs');

    const click$ = new Rx.Subject();
    const seed = 0;
    const testPromise = new Promise((resolve) => {
      resolve(1);
    })
    const count$ = click$.mergeScan((acc, promise) => of (promise)
      .flatMap(promise => promise)
      .map((one) => {
        console.log('acc', acc);
        return acc + one
      }), seed);
    count$.subscribe(x => console.log('value',x)); 

    click$.next(testPromise);
    click$.next(testPromise);
    click$.next(testPromise);
```

This output below, and the accumulator did not increase:

```
acc, 0
value, 1
acc, 0
value, 1
acc, 0
value, 1
```

but when I write code below:

```
const Rx = require('rxjs/Rx');
const {
  of ,
} = require('rxjs');

const click$ = new Rx.Subject();
const seed = 0;
const count$ = click$.mergeScan((acc, one) => of (one)
  .map((one) => {
    console.log('acc', acc);
    return acc + one
  }), seed);
count$.subscribe(x => console.log('value', x));

click$.next(1);
click$.next(1);
click$.next(1);
```

The output is:

```
acc, 0
value, 1
acc, 1
value, 2
acc, 2
value, 3
```

It is work right!

I don't know why, and how can I fix it?

Comment: If it works right, so what do you want to fix?

Comment: by the way , I want to write code like this, but it doesn't work.

```const asyncObservable = asyncAction$.mergeScan(acc, ({
  changeFn,
  promise
}) => of (promise)
.flatMap((promise) => promise)
.map((res) => changeFn(acc, res)),
defaultValue
)
```

Comment: null + 1 = 1 so my guess value from promise is not beeing resolved as it should, try convert promise to observable via http://reactivex.io/rxjs/file/es6/observable/fromPromise.js.html

Answer (score 2):

The whole problem is that Promises are resolved asynchronously but when you call `click$.next(testPromise)` multiple times this all is strictly synchronous so when the projection function for `mergeScan` is called `acc` is still `0` (because no promise has resolved yet).

You can see it will work as you expect by making `next()` calls asynchronous:

```
setTimeout(() => click$.next(testPromise));
```

Comment: yes, I tried it and found it's right. 
but I mast write like: 
```setTimeout(() => click$.next(testPromise),0); setTimeout(() => click$.next(testPromise),10); setTimeout(() => click$.next(testPromise),20);
```

Comment: and when I write all ```setTimeout(() => click$.next(testPromise),0);```

 it will give me the wrong result...
so tricky...

Comment: Just `setTimeout(() => click$.next(testPromise))` without setting any timeout is enough.

Comment: I tried it but print out same result...
the accumulator always 0 T_T